# How to "USE" a schema in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, azure

I can do:

```
USE db_name;
```

To have that database be the context. Is there a way to do the same for a schema, so that I can do a CREATE TABLE statement and it will automatically be placed within that schema?

```
CREATE TABLE jobs( -- insted of CREATE TABLE myschema.jobs
    job_id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    customer_id INT NOT NULL,
    description VARCHAR(200),
    created_at DATETIME2 NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: No, we can't. There isn't a `use schema` statement. In Azure SQL, the schema is mapping to the SQL user, if you don't specify the schema for user, the default schema is 'dbo'.  For example, `create table test` is same with `create table dbo.test`.

Comment: @LeonYue actually it looks like in SQL Database you can't eve use the `use database` either: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/use-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15.

Comment: Yes！All the operation is for current user database. Cross database query is different.

Comment: Hi @David542, do you have any other concerns? May I post it as answer?

Comment: @LeonYue do not assume. The default schema is an attribute of the user. It is usually set to "dbo" but it can be set to something else.

Comment: @David542 When creating an object without specifying a schema name, the default schema of the user will be used. Same thing applies to referencing objects by name only.  So set the default schema as desired and your newly created objects will be in that schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said, [USE statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/use-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) is not supported in Azure database. But it really means that we can not access another database resource by USE statement. For example, we can run the command in current database successfully:
[image]

In Azure SQL database, each user(include the server admin account) has the default schema [dbo], if you didn't specify it to other schema. When we create the table, it will automatically placed in the default schema.

Please see here:
[image]